# X Axis Chart Label not matching array data

Tags: vb.net, charts

Using VB.Net 2022, I'm creating a line chart to present trends.

I'm using an array to store dates which, when reviewing the data, are correct.

When I use chart.point.addxy(dataArray(i), loopcount) the label actually presents with the date 1 day before the actual date.

'EUC Chart
euc.Name = "euc-line"
'Change to a line graph.
euc.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
euc.XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date
euc.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
'For index As Integer = 1 To 3
euc.Points.AddXY(dateArray(5), EUCcount)
euc.Points.AddXY(dateArray(4), EUCcount)
euc.Points.AddXY(dateArray(3), EUCcount)
euc.Points.AddXY(dateArray(2), EUCcount)
euc.Points.AddXY(dateArray(1), EUCcount)
euc.Points.AddXY(dateArray(0), EUCcount)

```
    eucChart.Series.Add(euc)
```

The date in the array is created using the now date and then subtracting 7 and using the FirstDayofWeek.Monday. So the data in the array is an actual date.

I'm very confused as I can't see why it would do this. I've looked through the form object settings for the chart that I apply the above to, and I can't see anything that would take a date and subtract a day.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the item that was entering data into the array was set to date, change it to string and all is good.

Was: dim newDate as date

Now: dim newDate as string